# savedInstanceState is not being restored

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I am just starting out with Android and I faced the following issue:

I am trying to saveInstanceState when the new Activity is opened, and I need to restore that state when Activity is back to Visible state.

Here is my onSaveInstanceState method

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putParcelableArrayList("movies", (ArrayList<Movie>) movies);

    Log.v("onSaveInstanceState ", "SAVING STATE");
    Log.v("Saving State", outState.toString());
}
```

This is my onCreate method that should restore the previously saved instance state

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (savedInstanceState != null){
        Log.v("onCreate ", "EXISTING STATE");
        this.movies = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("movies");
    }else{
        Log.v("onCreate ", "EMPTY STATE");
    }

    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}
```

If you notice, in the onSaveInstanceState method, after I saved the instance I do toString() on the saved instance and it displays me the full instance with the values I saved. However when I am restoring the instance the savedInstanceState variable comes as null.

I am using an  Array of custom objects where each object implements Parcelable.

Below is the class:

```
public class Movie implements Parcelable {
private String title;
private String path;
private String overview;
private String releaseDate;
private double vote;

public Movie(String title, String overview, double vote, String releaseDate, String path) {
    this.title = title;
    this.overview = overview;
    this.vote = vote;
    this.releaseDate = releaseDate;
    this.path = path;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public String getPath() {
    return path;
}

public String getOverview() {
    return overview;
}

public String getReleaseDate() {
    return releaseDate;
}

public double getVote() {
    return vote;
}

protected Movie(Parcel source){
    this.title = source.readString();
    this.path = source.readString();
    this.overview = source.readString();
    this.releaseDate = source.readString();
    this.vote = source.readDouble();

}

public static final Creator<Movie> CREATOR = new Creator<Movie>() {
    @Override
    public Movie createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
        return new Movie(source);
    }

    @Override
    public Movie[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Movie[size];
    }
};

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(title);
    dest.writeSerializable(path);
    dest.writeString(overview);
    dest.writeString(releaseDate);
    dest.writeDouble(vote);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Movie{" +
            "title='" + title + '\'' +
            ", path='" + path + '\'' +
            ", overview='" + overview + '\'' +
            ", releaseDate='" + releaseDate + '\'' +
            ", vote=" + vote +
            '}';
}

}
```

I feel like I am saving it in the wrong way somehow. I followed the tutorial on how to do that. Please let me know what I am doing wrong. Thank you

[image]

Comment: So you're seeing the `EMPTY STATE` message then? I'm sorry if these are dumb questions.

Comment: @PaulBoddington Yes, it always jumps to else since instance is always null

Comment: I haven't studied it in great detail, but at a quick glance your code looks correct. The `Bundle` `savedInstanceState` is always `null` unless the system is trying to restore an `Activity` that the user navigated away from. If your application can have 2 different instances of the same `Activity` open, it won't create the 2nd instance using the bundle from the 1st. I usually save persistent data in `onPause`.

Comment: @PaulBoddington There is absolutely no chance of having to instances. I always delete the old one before starting the new run. Also in onCreateView() method there is only one startActivity(intent). Once the new Activity is open I simply click ''back" arrow to get back to the old one

Comment: I don't know what you mean by deleting an instance. The system determines which `Activity` instances exist or not.

Comment: @PaulBoddington idk if thats important. I am saving instancestate in the fragment, not in the actual MainActivity

Comment: I'm afraid I know nothing about `Fragment`s. I never use them. I find understanding the `Activity` life-cycle hard enough. Let me explain it like this. If you launch your app, then navigate away from it by pressing back, `onSaveInstanceState` will be called. But if you then click the app's launch icon again, the `Bundle` will be `null`, because as far as the system is concerned you are starting a new `Activity`, not resuming an old one.

Comment: @PaulBoddington Ok I understand what you mean. However my activity never closes (at least in this example) I am simply navigating to the childActivity and back

Comment: In that case I'm really confused. Calling `finish()` on a child activity should cause the parent activity to be restored. And if `onCreate()` is called in this situation, the `Bundle` should not be `null` because the system needs to use it to retrieve the `View` hierarchy. I think the problem lies in the way you are moving between the activities, rather than the code you have posted. I think you need to include the parts of the code where you launch the child activity and the parts of the code where you terminate the child activity. Don't include everything - just the relevant bits.

Comment: You're not returning from the child activity back to the parent activity using an `Intent` are you?

Comment: Nothing to do with the question itself but looks strange to write `dest.writeSerializable(path)` and read `this.path = source.readString()` even if we know that path is a `String` and `String` implements `Serializable`.

Comment: @PaulBoddington I am not sure what do you mean. I call the child activity with Intent and send info with extras. Then when I press <- arrow on top (Made by Android) it takes me back to parent activity. Also saving state works on device rotation, but does not work on when i go to child activity

Comment: @Jenny Ok, well that should work. When you press back <- the child should get finished and the parent restored. I'm a bit confused about what you're doing because `onCreate()` is almost never called in that situation at all, because the parent activity normally already exists (it only gets destroyed in between in order to free up resources, but that's very rare). I think you need to try to make a small example that we can all run and see where it's going wrong, because there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the code you've shown us.

Comment: @PaulBoddington following your comment. I did play around with my app and found out the following thing. There are 2 ways of clicking back [see picture on top] 1. Top arrow that has DetailActivity next to it. When I click that calls onStop() then when click the back arrow onDestroy() and onCreate(). 2. if i click the buttom arrow (the one where there 2 icons) it saves the state, calls onStop() and then onResume(). So my question now is how to make top array do the same behavior

Comment: @PaulBoddington I found the solution. You were right that my app had multiple instances open. See my answer below

Comment: I'm glad you found your solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem was resolved by adding to the MainActivity in the manifest file.

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

There were multiple instances of Activity created, therefore instance would no be saved.